# MINIMUM value using date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need the minimum date record from the below table , i tried this way but not working. any help will be great

```
 CREATE TABLE #TEST ( ID INT , EN_ID INT ,RN_ID  INT , VALUE VARCHAR(5) , DATE DATETIME  ) 

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (1234,1756,605,'13.2', '2019-08-14 05:29:00.000') ,(1234,1756,605,'15.5',  '2019-07-17 10:14:00.000')

SELECT ID, EN_ID,RN_ID,
VALUE ,MIN (DATE) MINDATE
FROM #TEST 
GROUP BY ID, EN_ID,RN_ID,VALUE
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Perhaps you're actually after a `TOP (1)`?

Comment: Consider: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7a01/1

Comment: when i run the above query i am getting 2 records, instead i need only one record that has minimum date in those 2 records

Comment: Since you group by `Value` and the rows have different `Value` values (?!) you get two result rows. Is that unexpected?

Comment: thats where i dont know how to solve it , i dont need 2 values. if i have same id and multiple dates then i need the least date row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of doing a TOP 1 or enumerating the query and then filtering

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, EN_ID,RN_ID, VALUE ,MIN (DATE) MINDATE
FROM #TEST 
GROUP BY ID, EN_ID,RN_ID,VALUE 

SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT ID, EN_ID,RN_ID, VALUE, DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, EN_ID,RN_ID ORDER BY DATE ASC) MINDATE
        FROM #TEST ) tbl
WHERE tbl.MINDATE = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As arce.est suggested in their second code sample, you can assign a row number that will let you filter the data as you've described it:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Id Int, En_Id Int, Rn_Id Int, [Value] VarChar(5), [Date] DateTime );

insert into @Samples ( Id, En_Id, Rn_Id, [Value], [Date] ) values
  ( 1234, 1756, 605,'13.2', '2019-08-14 05:29:00.000' ),
  ( 1234, 1756, 605,'15.5', '2019-07-17 10:14:00.000' );

select Id, En_Id, Rn_Id, [Value], [Date] -- , RN -- To see the values assigned.
  from (
    select Id, En_Id, Rn_Id, [Value], [Date],
      -- Generate a row number grouped by   Id, En_Id, Rn_Id   ordered by ascending   [Date] .
      Row_Number() over ( partition by Id, En_Id, Rn_Id order by [Date] ) as RN
      from @Samples ) as Placeholder
  where RN = 1; -- Output only the first row from each   Id, En_Id, Rn_Id   group.
```

You can comment out the `where` clause and add `RN` to the outer `select` list to see how the row numbers are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(DATE) AS MINDATE
FROM #TEST
```

That's all